# Disposing Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp throws 'System.ObjectDisposedException'

Tags: .net, wpf, signalr, owin

We have a self-hosted SignalR server in our WPF application. The WebApp gets started on application startup. On application exit we dispose of the WebApp.

```
    public void Start()
    {
        myWebApp = WebApp.Start<MyApp>(url);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (disposed) return;

        if (isDisposing)
            myWebApp.Dispose();

        disposed = true;
    }
```

The call to  myWebApp.Dispose() raises a  'System.ObjectDisposedException'.
Am I doing something wrong? The Microsoft.Owin.* dlls have the version 2.1.0 and the SignalR self host 2.0.3

**UPDATE**: Turns out this is the first chance exception which I can see in visual studio because the setting "break on clr exceptions" is active. This exception seems to be handled internally and does not bubble up into our code

Comment: It may be the first chance in your case but if NLog middleware is used: `appBuilder.UseNLog()` it logs exception as Error.

Answer (score 3):

After exploring the Katana source code, I found a reason for this problem. It is the `Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener.ProcessRequestsAsync()` method. It starts while-loop containing `_listener.GetContextAsync()` call of a private `HttpListener` instance in try-catch section.

Also class implements `IDisposable` and contains a `Dispose()` method. This method disposes the private `HttpListener` instance.

When you call `WebApp.Start()` it returns an instance of `IDisposable`, that only has `Dispose()` method, that disposes `OwinHttpListener`.

So, when you dispose it, you call its `Dispose()` method of `OwinHttpListener`, which disposes the private `HttpListener`.

But at the same time `ProcessRequestsAsync()` calls `_listener.GetContextAsync()`, but `_listener` is already disposed and throws `ObjectDisposedException`. `catch` block log the exception and returns from `ProcessRequestsAsync()`.

I think, that double check lock in `ProcessRequestsAsync()` may be a good option.

```
private async void ProcessRequestsAsync()
{
    while (_listener.IsListening && CanAcceptMoreRequests)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _currentOutstandingAccepts);
        HttpListenerContext context;
        try
        {
            context = await _listener.GetContextAsync();
        }
        (SOME_OTHER_CATCHES)
        catch (ObjectDisposedException ode)
        {
            // These happen if HttpListener has been disposed
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref _currentOutstandingAccepts);
            LogHelper.LogException(_logger, "Accept", ode);
            return;
        }
        (SOME_OTHER_CODE)
    }
}

public void Dispose()
{
    if (_listener.IsListening)
    {
        _listener.Stop();
    }

    ((IDisposable)_listener).Dispose();
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to fix the problem without rewriting Katana. Is it right?

Comment: @SerG yes, it is. All you can do is leave object, returned by WebApp.Start(), undisposed.

Comment: I'm not sure where double-checked locking would help here. However, it does seem like the Dispose method needs to do more to shut down that async process which is still trying to do things while the listener is being disposed of underneath it.